# npm install in any project showing error 409

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

*npm install* command shows below error in any project for me

Here are the version details of node & npm:

```
node -v
8.11.1  

npm -v
5.6.0
```

Error I am getting is below:

```
npm ERR! code E409
npm ERR! 409 Conflict: gulp-jshint@1.12.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mndco\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-03T08_10_01_188Z-debug.log
```

[eslamblog.ir](https://eslamblog.ir)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you share the contents of the log in the output, we would have a better chance in helping you. Also, please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: formatted the question content
also added an answer

Comment: My problem was solved by deleting the configured proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*npm install* reads packages & their version, present in *package.json*

looks like, it is installing *gulp-jshint@1.12.0*
that is, *gulp-jshint* package of version *1.12.0*

May be, it is old version, you need to upgrade your *gulp-jshint* libary to latest, so doing below may help:

1. Make a copy of package.json file on desktop or somewhere (or make a copy of all files/project directory if you need).
2. run below command:

   ```
     npm install jshint gulp-jshint --save-dev
   ```

install source: https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint

3. now run *npm install*

Hope that will help.